# Issues with mutate() and case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm currently trying to mutate a variable using dplyr, but continuously receive an error of unknown symbol in my data mutation. assn3 is a df, female is a column in the data set I am trying to label as female2.

I'm looking to either rewrite or create a new column.
I first tried this:

```
library(dplyr)
assn3 %>% mutate(female2 = case_when(assn3$female == 1 ~ 'female'
                                     assn3$female == 0 ~ 'male'))
```

I also tried this:

```
library(dplyr)
assn3 %>% 
  mutate(gender2 = case_when(assn3$female == 1 ~ 'female'
                             assn3$female == 0 ~ 'male'))
```

both times I got the following error:
Error: unexpected symbol in: *insert input*
I also tried previously functioning lines from other scripts I used, and they are no longer working either.
How can I fix this or alternatively, what is a function that will get me the same result?

Comment: the comma is missing after `assn3$female == 1 ~ 'female'`

Answer (score 0):

Use recode instead

```
library(tidyverse)
assn3$female <- recode(assn3$female,
"1" = "female",
"0" = "male")
```